# SQL Server 2000 Query of total value and value from max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have this RoomTable with value

```
SID   Room   Date        APhase   BPhase   ACount  BCount
1     One    10/28/2012  4        5         3       6
2     One    10/29/2012  2        3        -1      -1
3     One    10/30/2012  4        5         7      -1
4     Two    10/28/2012  8        3         2       3
5     Two    10/30/2012  3        5         4       6
6     Three  10/29/2012  5        8         2      -1
7     Three  10/30/2012  5        6        -1       4
8     Four   10/29/2012  6        2        -1      -1
9     Four   10/30/2012  5        8        -1      -1
```

What I want is to return the following:

1. Total sum of APhase and BPhase of each Room.
2. Value of ACount and BCount from max date of each Room
3. If ACount value is -1 then use the previous date. Same as BCount.
4. If ACount value is -1 and the previous date is -1 and so on. Then use 0. Same as BCount.

I can get the query of number 1 with this query

```
SELECT Room, sum(APhase) as TotalAPhase, sum(BPhase) as TotalBPhase 
FROM RoomTable 
WHERE Date between '10/28/2012' and '10/30/2012'
group by Room
order by Room
```

But I'm confused on how to include the number 2-4 query.

This is the output I want

```
Room  TotalAPhase  TotalBPhase  ACount   BCount
One   10           13           7        6
Two   11           8            4        6
Three 10           13           2        4
Four  11           10           0        0
```

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this works for your case:

```
SELECT 
Room
,SUM(APhase) AS TotalAPhase
,SUM(BPhase) AS TotalBPhase 
,ISNULL((    SELECT TOP 1 RT1.ACount 
             FROM RoomTable RT1 
             WHERE RT1.Room = RT.Room 
                AND RT1.ACount != -1
             ORDER BY RT1.Date DESC
), 0) AS ACount
,ISNULL((   SELECT TOP 1 RT2.BCount 
            FROM RoomTable RT2
            WHERE RT2.Room = RT.Room 
               AND RT2.BCount != -1
            ORDER BY RT2.Date DESC
), 0) AS BCount

FROM RoomTable RT
--WHERE Date between '10/28/2012' and '10/30/2012'
GROUP BY Room
ORDER BY Room
```

I am not sure if you really need that where clause so I commented it out. And the value of TotalBPhase for Room Three on your result table should be 14, as can be seen from [this SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc787/1).

Comment: I can't make this work on SQL Server 2000, it says Column 'RT.Room' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function...

Comment: @quinekxi: Try prefixing `Room` with `RT.` in GROUP BY (a wild guess).

Comment: @AndriyM: That was really a good a wild guess. Now its working as what I want. Thanks and Thank you yildizm85

Answer (score 2):

You can use the answer by @yildizm85 or if you want more performant code, you can break down all tasks on smaller steps and use table variables to achieve the same. See below query...

```
declare @roomResult table
(Room nvarchar(50), maxadate datetime, maxbdate datetime, TotalAPhase int , TotalBPhase int , acount int, bcount int)

insert into @roomResult 
SELECT Room, null,null,sum(APhase) as TotalAPhase, sum(BPhase) as TotalBPhase ,0,0
FROM RoomTable 
group by Room
order by Room

update @roomresult 
set maxadate = mxdate  
from 
(
select room roomname, max( date) mxdate  from
(
select room, date , case when acount = -1 then null else acount end acount , case when bcount = -1 then null else bcount end bcount 
from roomtable ) as a where a.acount is not null
 group by room
) b inner join @roomresult c on b.roomname = c.room


update @roomresult 
set maxbdate = mxdate  
from 
(
select room roomname, max( date) mxdate  from
(
select room, date , case when bcount = -1 then null else bcount end bcount 
from roomtable ) as a where a.bcount is not null
 group by room
) b inner join @roomresult c on b.roomname = c.room

update @roomresult 
set acount = r.acount
from @roomresult rr inner join roomtable r
on rr.room = r.room and rr.maxadate = r.date

update @roomresult 
set bcount = r.bcount
from @roomresult rr inner join roomtable r
on rr.room = r.room and rr.maxbdate = r.date

select Room,TotalAPhase,TotalbPhase,ACount,BCount From @roomResult
```

Comment: aasanar na.  mhanun tar mhanalo tumhi master disata database madhale.

Comment: logically pahayala gell tar correct watat aahe tumacha uttar.

Answer (score -1):

You can try query something like this>>>

```
SELECT Room, sum(APhase) as TotalAPhase, sum(BPhase) as TotalBPhase 
FROM RoomTable 
WHERE Date =(select max(Date) from RoomTable group by Room order by Room)
and ACount=(update RoomTable set ACount=0 where ACount<0) and and ACount=(update RoomTable set BCount=0 where BCount<0)
group by Room 
order by Room
```